# Http PUT deletes data that hasn't been changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, httprequest, put

I am trying to edit a JSON data base of shifts. I am writing in Javascript using react.
This is my understanding of the PUT syntax:

```
const editShift = async (changed, id) => {

  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/shifts/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT', 
    headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json' 
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(changed)
 })
 const data = await res.json()
 setShifts([...shifts, data])
}
```

**data.json:**

```
{
  "shifts": [
    {
      "title": "test",
      "startDate": "2018-06-25T07:30:00.000Z",
      "endDate": "2018-06-25T08:00:00.000Z",
      "allDay": false,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "test2",
      "startDate": "2018-06-28T07:30:00.000Z",
      "endDate": "2018-06-28T08:00:00.000Z",
      "allDay": false,
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The result is that the new shift will hold only the fields that have been changed and delete the rest. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to send the whole updated shift into the changed field, with the fields that were not changed. I don't know why but it works so okay.

Answer (score 1):

To get previous shifts you should use a callback inside setShifts like:

```
setShifts(prevShifts => ([...prevShifts, data]))
```

Comment: This is after the put request is done so this can't be it, what are the benefits of using the callback?

Comment: @Kahalon benefit of using a callback is that you are always sure you are using latest version of a value there because it could be changed in meantime so using  `shifts` doesn't give you 100% that it is the latest value

Comment: cheers, I am using it with my working addShift POST and it works nicely, but the PUT is still broken

Comment: @Kahalon what is the structure of shifts?

Comment: JSON structure, I have updated my post with an example of two shifts.

Comment: Found 1 typo of mine, I had written: 'application/json;'  and not 'application/json'. now the issue that it deletes the data that hasn't been changed, I will try to send it the whole new shift

Answer (score 1):

The PUT request should work like that.

A PUT request should PUT the data into place of the old record.
You would want to use a PATCH request for only PATCHing data upon the old record.

That set aside, it depends on your /shifts endpoint on how this is actually handled.

Answer (score 0):

For a question like this, it'd be helpful if you posted before and after examples of data

- database empty
- request #1, payload equals X
- request #2, payload equals Y

Also, knowing what your Server handler is doing would help determine what's going on. I have a feeling what's happening is something like this

```js
// API handler
(req) => {
  const dbData = getDBData();
  dbData.shifts = req.shifts; // overwrite old with new
}
```

When what you need is something like

```js
(req) => {
  const dbData = getDBData();
  req.shifts.forEach((newShiftData) => {
    const shiftId = newShiftData.id;

    if (dbData[shiftId]) {
      dbData[shiftId] = { ...dbData[shiftId], ...newShiftData }; // merge old with new
    }
  });

  // - check if data changed
  // - update DB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` requests *replace* all the data at the target URI. They don't automatically merge changes.

It's not clear if you are the author of this API or just a consumer, but if you are consuming the API you should either look for a different API that lets you only send edits (HTTP method might be POST or PATCH), or you need to send the entire list of shifts.

Alternatively it might also be possible that there's a specific endpoint for each shift, so you can send exactly 1 PUT request to a shift endpoint just to edit that specific endpoint.